show that $ \frac{(n+1)^{r+1} - (n+1)}{(r+1)!} = \frac{S_1}{r!1!} + \frac{S_2}{(r-1)!2!} + \dots + \frac{S_r}{1!r!} $
Question in full:
Given,  $S_{r} = 1^r + 2^r + \dots +n^r$, where $r$ is a positive integer, show that $ \frac{(n+1)^{r+1} - (n+1)}{(r+1)!} = \frac{S_1}{r!1!} + \frac{S_2}{(r-1)!2!} + \dots + \frac{S_r}{1!r!} $,  by considering the expression $(1 + x)^{r + 1} - x^{r+1}$, or otherwise.
My attempts:
I investigated to see how the expression, $(1 + x)^{r + 1} - x^{r+1}$ might relate in two ways:
$(1)$.  For $ r = 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots $, expanding gives:
$1$
$1 + 2x$
$1 + 3x +3x^2$
$1 + 4x +6x^2 +4x^3$
$1 + 5x +10x^2 +10x^3 + 5x^4$
$\dots$ and so on $\dots$, the coefficients being the entries in Pascal's Triangle with the $1$'s stripped on the right edge of the triangle.
$(2)$. Next I know the result: $ \sum_{x=1}^{n} \{ (1 + x)^{r + 1} - x^{r+1} \} = (n + 1)^{r + 1} - 1$
I can't relate either of these bits of knowledge for showing the given equation holds true.
$(3)$. Instead, I tested cases for $ r = 1, 2, \dots $ as follows:
$ r = 1, $ LHS: $\frac{(n + 1 )^2 - (n + 1)}{2!} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{S_1}{1!.1!}$ on RHS
$ r = 2, $ LHS: $\frac{(n + 1 )^3 - (n + 1)}{3!} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6} \dots (1)$;
RHS: $ \frac{S_1}{2!} + \frac{S_2}{2!} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6}\right] =\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6} $ This is the same result as $(1)$.
So it looks as thought the right hand side of the equation holds with the left hand side, for $r = 1$ and $r = 2$.
Next I tried to show the formula holds using Mathematical Induction.
I started by writing the general form for the summation on the right as, $ \sum_{m = 1}^r \frac{S_m}{(r + 1 - m)!m!}$. (I hope the dummy variable $m$ is ok to use?)
From the previous results, the equation proved consistent for $m = 1$ and $m = 2$, now assuming the formula holds for $m = k$, gives,
$\frac{(n + 1 )^{k+1} - (n + 1)}{(k+1)!} = \frac{S_1}{k!1!} + \frac{S_2}{(k-1)!2!} + \frac{S_3}{(k-2)!3!} + \dots + \frac{S_k}{(r + 1 - k)!k!}   $
Now try for $m = (k + 1) $ gives on RHS,
$ \frac{S_1}{k!1!} + \frac{S_2}{(k-1)!2!} + \frac{S_3}{(k-2)!3!} + \dots + \frac{S_k}{(r + 1 - k)!k!} + \frac{S_{k+1}}{(r - k)!(k + 1)!}  $
On LHS: $\frac{(n + 1 )^{k+2} - (n + 1)}{(k+2)!} \dots$. I think I've reached the limit of my knowledge at this point. I can't see the conclusion!
To summarize; I am not seeing how to apply the expression $(1 + x)^{r + 1} - x^{r+1}$, and I'm not convinced the OTHERWISE method is to use Mathematical Induction ... if it is, I'm not sure how to conclude the last part testing with $m = (k + 1) $.
Please note this is A-level Further Mathematics at school 6th Form level, not university Analysis level.
Many thanks in advance for any help!

Both in the title and the beginning of the body of the post, $n+r$ should be $n+1$, as suggested by the rest of the post.

Corrected! Sorry about that. Should have been (n + 1) not (n + r).

$$
(n+1)^{r+1} -1 = \sum_{x=1}^n [(1+x)^{r+1} - x^{r+1}] = \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r+1}{k} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r+1}{k} S_k.
$$
Moving the $k=0$ term to the LHS and dividing by $(r+1)!$ gives the desired equation.

Am I right, you applied Binomial expansion to (1 + x)^{r+1}, then rearranged to make this equivalent to sum of x^k by introducing double sum ?

@Nik yes that’s right.

Thanks Pranay, that is so elegant!

@Nik. Please accept the answer if it’s helpful.

Can the solution be done without the double summation? And is there an Otherwise method?

@Nik I’m not aware of another method, but it’s likely there’s one.

Pranay thank you. I am only starting to learn about double summations. Do you know if there is a link to help explain the double sum in the answer?

@Nik you can read about the commutativity of the summation and many other properties in the Wikipedia article on summation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation
